# how to solve Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs in FMDB

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite

i am using FMDB wrapper i used 
this code

```
- (BOOL)update:(NSString *) Body fromValue:(NSString *)froms {

    BOOL success = NO;
    FMResultSet *rs;
//I have **searchTable** and in that folder name **OFFICE**  

    rs = [self.database executeQuery:@"select searchId,body from searchTable WHERE folder = 'OFFICE'"];


    NSInteger primaryKey = -1;
    NSString *body = nil;
    NSString *md5OfSearchEmailBody = nil;
    while ([rs next]) {
        primaryKey  = [rs intForColumn:@"searchId"];
        body = [rs stringForColumn:@"body"];
    }           

    [rs close];
    return success;
}
```

first time

```
- (BOOL)update:(NSString *) Body fromValue:(NSString *)froms{
}
```

method working fine. in the loop second time it's not working

> **Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs**

how to solve this problem

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I see you marked an answer as correct but I would like to know what you did, because I'm having the same issue. Did you fix the problem or did you switch to Core Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the  `[rs close];`

May be it is releasing or closing the DB.

===================================================

Better use CoreData to implement sqlite in your application.

Why to use external library, when a better internal library is available in the Application. You don't need to remove your sqlite table. You can easily migrate your existing database to CoreData.

Comment: FYI May better to use external library, when it is better than the internal library available in the Application.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error because call [database close] before call [resultSet next].

```
FMDatabase *db;

[db open];

FMResultSet *set = [db executeQuery:@"some select"];

[db close];

while ([set next])
{
    // get Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs
}

[set close];
```

Should call [database close] after call [resultSet next]

```
FMDatabase *db;

[db open];

FMResultSet *set = [db executeQuery:@"some select"];

while ([set next])
{
    // no error
}

[set close];
[db close];
```

Answer (score 0):

i was getting out of memory even after [rs close]; so i used :

```
while ([rs next]) {
        @autoreleasepool
        { 
          //stuff like......[rs stringForColumn:@"category_id"];...
        }
                 } 
       [rs close];
```

i solved my mory growth as well as out of memory error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. So basically I had two functions, say func1() and func2().

In func1() I was doing the following:

1.) Generating the result set.
2.) Printing the result( To Test)
3.) Calling func2() with the result set as an argument.

In func2(), I was facing the error while I was trying to iterate through the result set received from func1().

When I removed the code in func1() (Step 2), the error was gone!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the out of memory issue, I had to set my code like below to check at the end of the loop if loop == LocationCount then break the loop. If I left it out it would [rs next] which would then give me the Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs.
I would recommend to do something similar so [rs next] doesn't so more than what required for your function.

```
int loop = 0;
while ([rs next])
    {
         // additional code here
        loop = loop + 1;
        if (loop == LoopMaxCount) {
                break;
         } else {
                [rs next];
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I by mistake was calling `[rs next]` after the previous call of `[rs next]` returned `false`.